# vector subscript out of range C++ OpenCV camera calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am trying Martin Peris's OpenCV stereo camera calibration code from this link (http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html). When I use his given camera calibration images it works fine. But when I try my images it gives the following error:

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C"\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll

File: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\include\vector\

Line: 1140

Expression: vector subscript out of range

I am running the code on Windows 64 bit. I built the project using CMAKE. The only way I know to run this program is to open developer command prompt for VS2012. Then CD to the debug directory of my project. Then call the program using this command: "stereo_camera_calibrate list.txt 9 6 2.2" as explained in the blog linked above. The problem with running this console application through the command prompt is that I DO NOT KNOW WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENED IN THE CODE!

Update: I just added couple of lines of code to check if the image is loaded or not. apparently the images are not being loaded since I get this msg on screen "image not loaded"! my images are BMP. is there any problems with loading .bmp images using cvLoadImage?

here is the code, any help is appreciated

```
#pragma warning( disable: 4996 )
/* *************** License:**************************
   Oct. 3, 2008
   Right to use this code in any way you want without warrenty, support or any guarentee of it working.

   BOOK: It would be nice if you cited it:
   Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library
     by Gary Bradski and Adrian Kaehler
     Published by O'Reilly Media, October 3, 2008

   AVAILABLE AT: 
     http://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/0596516134
     Or: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130/
     ISBN-10: 0596516134 or: ISBN-13: 978-0596516130    

   OTHER OPENCV SITES:
   * The source code is on sourceforge at:
     http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/
   * The OpenCV wiki page (As of Oct 1, 2008 this is down for changing over servers, but should come back):
     http://opencvlibrary.sourceforge.net/
   * An active user group is at:
     http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/
   * The minutes of weekly OpenCV development meetings are at:
     http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV
   ************************************************** */

/*
    Modified by Martin Peris Martorell (info@martinperis.com) in order to accept some configuration
    parameters and store all the calibration data as xml files.

*/

#include "cv.h"
#include "cxmisc.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

//
// Given a list of chessboard images, the number of corners (nx, ny)
// on the chessboards, and a flag: useCalibrated for calibrated (0) or
// uncalibrated (1: use cvStereoCalibrate(), 2: compute fundamental
// matrix separately) stereo. Calibrate the cameras and display the
// rectified results along with the computed disparity images.
//
static void
StereoCalib(const char* imageList, int nx, int ny, int useUncalibrated, float _squareSize)
{
    int displayCorners = 1;
    int showUndistorted = 1;
    bool isVerticalStereo = false;//OpenCV can handle left-right
                                      //or up-down camera arrangements
    const int maxScale = 1;
    const float squareSize = _squareSize; //Chessboard square size in cm
    FILE* f = fopen(imageList, "rt");
    int i, j, lr, nframes, n = nx*ny, N = 0;
    vector<string> imageNames[2];
    vector<CvPoint3D32f> objectPoints;
    vector<CvPoint2D32f> points[2];
    vector<int> npoints;
    vector<uchar> active[2];
    vector<CvPoint2D32f> temp(n);
    CvSize imageSize = {0,0};
    // ARRAY AND VECTOR STORAGE:
    double M1[3][3], M2[3][3], D1[5], D2[5];
    double R[3][3], T[3], E[3][3], F[3][3];
    double Q[4][4];
    CvMat _M1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, M1 );
    CvMat _M2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, M2 );
    CvMat _D1 = cvMat(1, 5, CV_64F, D1 );
    CvMat _D2 = cvMat(1, 5, CV_64F, D2 );
    CvMat _R = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R );
    CvMat _T = cvMat(3, 1, CV_64F, T );
    CvMat _E = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, E );
    CvMat _F = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, F );
    CvMat _Q = cvMat(4,4, CV_64F, Q);
    if( displayCorners )
        cvNamedWindow( "corners", 1 );
// READ IN THE LIST OF CHESSBOARDS:
    if( !f )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not open file %s\n", imageList );
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        char buf[1024];
        int count = 0, result=0;
        lr = i % 2;
        vector<CvPoint2D32f>& pts = points[lr];
        if( !fgets( buf, sizeof(buf)-3, f ))
            break;
        size_t len = strlen(buf);
        while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]))
            buf[--len] = '\0';
        if( buf[0] == '#')
            continue;
        IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( buf, 0 );
        if(img == NULL)
            printf("image not loaded \n");
        else
            printf("Loaded image \n");
        if( !img )
            break;
        imageSize = cvGetSize(img);
        imageNames[lr].push_back(buf);
    //FIND CHESSBOARDS AND CORNERS THEREIN:
        for( int s = 1; s <= maxScale; s++ )
        {
            IplImage* timg = img;
            if( s > 1 )
            {
                timg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width*s,img->height*s),
                    img->depth, img->nChannels );
                cvResize( img, timg, CV_INTER_CUBIC );
            }
            result = cvFindChessboardCorners( timg, cvSize(nx, ny),
                &temp[0], &count,
                CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH |
                CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
            if( timg != img )
                cvReleaseImage( &timg );
            if( result || s == maxScale )
                for( j = 0; j < count; j++ )
            {
                temp[j].x /= s;
                temp[j].y /= s;
            }
            if( result )
                break;
        }
        if( displayCorners )
        {
            printf("%s\n", buf);
            IplImage* cimg = cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8, 3 );
            cvCvtColor( img, cimg, CV_GRAY2BGR );
            cvDrawChessboardCorners( cimg, cvSize(nx, ny), &temp[0],
                count, result );
            cvShowImage( "corners", cimg );
            cvReleaseImage( &cimg );
            if( cvWaitKey(0) == 27 ) //Allow ESC to quit
                exit(-1);
        }
        else
            putchar('.');
        N = pts.size();
        pts.resize(N + n, cvPoint2D32f(0,0));
        active[lr].push_back((uchar)result);
    //assert( result != 0 );
        if( result )
        {
         //Calibration will suffer without subpixel interpolation
            cvFindCornerSubPix( img, &temp[0], count,
                cvSize(11, 11), cvSize(-1,-1),
                cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,
                30, 0.01) );
            copy( temp.begin(), temp.end(), pts.begin() + N );
        }
        cvReleaseImage( &img );
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
// HARVEST CHESSBOARD 3D OBJECT POINT LIST:
    nframes = active[0].size();//Number of good chessboads found
    objectPoints.resize(nframes*n);
    for( i = 0; i < ny; i++ )
        for( j = 0; j < nx; j++ )
        objectPoints[i*nx + j] = cvPoint3D32f(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0);
    for( i = 1; i < nframes; i++ )
        copy( objectPoints.begin(), objectPoints.begin() + n,
        objectPoints.begin() + i*n );
    npoints.resize(nframes,n);
    N = nframes*n;
    CvMat _objectPoints = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &objectPoints[0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0] );
    CvMat _npoints = cvMat(1, npoints.size(), CV_32S, &npoints[0] );
    cvSetIdentity(&_M1);
    cvSetIdentity(&_M2);
    cvZero(&_D1);
    cvZero(&_D2);

// CALIBRATE THE STEREO CAMERAS
    printf("Running stereo calibration ...");
    fflush(stdout);
    cvStereoCalibrate( &_objectPoints, &_imagePoints1,
        &_imagePoints2, &_npoints,
        &_M1, &_D1, &_M2, &_D2,
        imageSize, &_R, &_T, &_E, &_F,
        cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+
        CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
        CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
        CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
        CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH );
    printf(" done\n");
// CALIBRATION QUALITY CHECK
// because the output fundamental matrix implicitly
// includes all the output information,
// we can check the quality of calibration using the
// epipolar geometry constraint: m2^t*F*m1=0
    vector<CvPoint3D32f> lines[2];
    points[0].resize(N);
    points[1].resize(N);
    _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0] );
    _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0] );
    lines[0].resize(N);
    lines[1].resize(N);
    CvMat _L1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &lines[0][0]);
    CvMat _L2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &lines[1][0]);
//Always work in undistorted space
    cvUndistortPoints( &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints1,
        &_M1, &_D1, 0, &_M1 );
    cvUndistortPoints( &_imagePoints2, &_imagePoints2,
        &_M2, &_D2, 0, &_M2 );
    cvComputeCorrespondEpilines( &_imagePoints1, 1, &_F, &_L1 );
    cvComputeCorrespondEpilines( &_imagePoints2, 2, &_F, &_L2 );
    double avgErr = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        double err = fabs(points[0][i].x*lines[1][i].x +
            points[0][i].y*lines[1][i].y + lines[1][i].z)
            + fabs(points[1][i].x*lines[0][i].x +
            points[1][i].y*lines[0][i].y + lines[0][i].z);
        avgErr += err;
    }
    printf( "avg err = %g\n", avgErr/(nframes*n) );
//COMPUTE AND DISPLAY RECTIFICATION
    if( showUndistorted )
    {
        CvMat* mx1 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* my1 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* mx2 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,

            imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* my2 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* img1r = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_8U );
        CvMat* img2r = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_8U );
        CvMat* disp = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_16S );
        CvMat* vdisp = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height,
            imageSize.width, CV_8U );
        CvMat* pair;
        double R1[3][3], R2[3][3], P1[3][4], P2[3][4];
        CvMat _R1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R1);
        CvMat _R2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R2);
// IF BY CALIBRATED (BOUGUET'S METHOD)
        if( useUncalibrated == 0 )
        {
            CvMat _P1 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P1);
            CvMat _P2 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P2);
            cvStereoRectify( &_M1, &_M2, &_D1, &_D2, imageSize,
                &_R, &_T,
                &_R1, &_R2, &_P1, &_P2, &_Q,
                0/*CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY*/ );
            isVerticalStereo = fabs(P2[1][3]) > fabs(P2[0][3]);
    //Precompute maps for cvRemap()
            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M1,&_D1,&_R1,&_P1,mx1,my1);
            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M2,&_D2,&_R2,&_P2,mx2,my2);

    //Save parameters
            cvSave("M1.xml",&_M1);
            cvSave("D1.xml",&_D1);
            cvSave("R1.xml",&_R1);
            cvSave("P1.xml",&_P1);
            cvSave("M2.xml",&_M2);
            cvSave("D2.xml",&_D2);
            cvSave("R2.xml",&_R2);
            cvSave("P2.xml",&_P2);
            cvSave("Q.xml",&_Q);
            cvSave("mx1.xml",mx1);
            cvSave("my1.xml",my1);
            cvSave("mx2.xml",mx2);
            cvSave("my2.xml",my2);

        }
//OR ELSE HARTLEY'S METHOD
        else if( useUncalibrated == 1 || useUncalibrated == 2 )
     // use intrinsic parameters of each camera, but
     // compute the rectification transformation directly
     // from the fundamental matrix
        {
            double H1[3][3], H2[3][3], iM[3][3];
            CvMat _H1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, H1);
            CvMat _H2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, H2);
            CvMat _iM = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, iM);
    //Just to show you could have independently used F
            if( useUncalibrated == 2 )
                cvFindFundamentalMat( &_imagePoints1,
                &_imagePoints2, &_F);
            cvStereoRectifyUncalibrated( &_imagePoints1,
                &_imagePoints2, &_F,
                imageSize,
                &_H1, &_H2, 3);
            cvInvert(&_M1, &_iM);
            cvMatMul(&_H1, &_M1, &_R1);
            cvMatMul(&_iM, &_R1, &_R1);
            cvInvert(&_M2, &_iM);
            cvMatMul(&_H2, &_M2, &_R2);
            cvMatMul(&_iM, &_R2, &_R2);
    //Precompute map for cvRemap()
            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M1,&_D1,&_R1,&_M1,mx1,my1);

            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M2,&_D1,&_R2,&_M2,mx2,my2);
        }
        else
            assert(0);
        cvNamedWindow( "rectified", 1 );
// RECTIFY THE IMAGES AND FIND DISPARITY MAPS
        if( !isVerticalStereo )
            pair = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width*2,
            CV_8UC3 );
        else
            pair = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height*2, imageSize.width,
            CV_8UC3 );
//Setup for finding stereo corrrespondences
        CvStereoBMState *BMState = cvCreateStereoBMState();
        assert(BMState != 0);
        BMState->preFilterSize=41;
        BMState->preFilterCap=31;
        BMState->SADWindowSize=41;
        BMState->minDisparity=-64;
        BMState->numberOfDisparities=128;
        BMState->textureThreshold=10;
        BMState->uniquenessRatio=15;
        for( i = 0; i < nframes; i++ )
        {
            IplImage* img1=cvLoadImage(imageNames[0][i].c_str(),0);
            IplImage* img2=cvLoadImage(imageNames[1][i].c_str(),0);
            if( img1 && img2 )
            {
                CvMat part;
                cvRemap( img1, img1r, mx1, my1 );
                cvRemap( img2, img2r, mx2, my2 );
                if( !isVerticalStereo || useUncalibrated != 0 )
                {
              // When the stereo camera is oriented vertically,
              // useUncalibrated==0 does not transpose the
              // image, so the epipolar lines in the rectified
              // images are vertical. Stereo correspondence
              // function does not support such a case.
                    cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM( img1r, img2r, disp,
                        BMState);
                    cvNormalize( disp, vdisp, 0, 256, CV_MINMAX );
                    cvNamedWindow( "disparity" );
                    cvShowImage( "disparity", vdisp );
                }
                if( !isVerticalStereo )
                {
                    cvGetCols( pair, &part, 0, imageSize.width );
                    cvCvtColor( img1r, &part, CV_GRAY2BGR );
                    cvGetCols( pair, &part, imageSize.width,
                        imageSize.width*2 );
                    cvCvtColor( img2r, &part, CV_GRAY2BGR );
                    for( j = 0; j < imageSize.height; j += 16 )
                        cvLine( pair, cvPoint(0,j),
                        cvPoint(imageSize.width*2,j),
                        CV_RGB(0,255,0));
                }
                else
                {
                    cvGetRows( pair, &part, 0, imageSize.height );
                    cvCvtColor( img1r, &part, CV_GRAY2BGR );
                    cvGetRows( pair, &part, imageSize.height,
                        imageSize.height*2 );
                    cvCvtColor( img2r, &part, CV_GRAY2BGR );
                    for( j = 0; j < imageSize.width; j += 16 )
                        cvLine( pair, cvPoint(j,0),
                        cvPoint(j,imageSize.height*2),
                        CV_RGB(0,255,0));
                }
                cvShowImage( "rectified", pair );
                if( cvWaitKey() == 27 )
                    break;
            }
            cvReleaseImage( &img1 );
            cvReleaseImage( &img2 );
        }
        cvReleaseStereoBMState(&BMState);
        cvReleaseMat( &mx1 );
        cvReleaseMat( &my1 );
        cvReleaseMat( &mx2 );
        cvReleaseMat( &my2 );
        cvReleaseMat( &img1r );
        cvReleaseMat( &img2r );
        cvReleaseMat( &disp );
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nx, ny;
    float squareSize;
    int fail = 0;
    //Check command line
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: %s imageList nx ny squareSize\n",argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr,"\t imageList : Filename of the image list (string). Example : list.txt\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"\t nx : Number of horizontal squares (int > 0). Example : 9\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"\t ny : Number of vertical squares (int > 0). Example : 6\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"\t squareSize : Size of a square (float > 0). Example : 2.5\n");
        return 1;
    } 

        nx = atoi(argv[2]);
    ny = atoi(argv[3]);
    squareSize = (float)atof(argv[4]);

    if (nx <= 0)
    {
        fail = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: nx value can not be <= 0\n");
    }
    if (ny <= 0)
    {
        fail = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: ny value can not be <= 0\n");
    }   
    if (squareSize <= 0.0)
    {
        fail = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: squareSize value can not be <= 0\n");
    }   

    if(fail != 0) return 1;

    StereoCalib(argv[1], nx, ny, 0, squareSize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `cvResize(img,img);` after `IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( buf, 0 );`

Comment: Now it returns this error: Debug Error! R6010 -abort() has been called

Comment: Don't you have Visual Studio installed? Why cannot you launch the program and then attach the debugger to it? If you cannot run it immediately from IDE you can insert something like DebugBreak() somewhere at the start (or wait until assert pops up) and then launch the debugger at request.

Comment: Can you please explain how to "attach the debugger to it"? I can run the program from VS using "start without debugging" but then this message pops up saying how to use this program and what are the arguments/inputs to this program.